# Importing one file from another

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database-connection

Hello all I wanna create a ASP.NET c# file named "DBconnect.aspx" where I will provide all my MYSQL database settings. I would like to import these settings without re-entering database details to another page.

Of course have to mention the namespace with Public class but I do need to sample syntax to make this.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Web.config is designed for this purpose. Do you some unusual requirement you have not mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`, you should really just use [connection strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) in your `web.config`.

The syntax for a MySQL connection string can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql).